# Angular Material md-tabs enabling all tabs switches to first tab

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

The default behavior of md-tabs switches to the last tab when i disable all tabs and switches back to the first when i enable all tabs.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dpKPrQ

```
<md-content class="md-padding">
<md-tabs md-selected="selectedIndex" md-border-bottom="" md-autoselect="">
  <md-tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-disabled="disabled" label="{{tab.title}}">
    <div class="demo-tab tab{{$index%4}}" style="padding: 25px; text-align: center;">
      <div ng-bind="tab.content"></div>
      <br>

    </div>
  </md-tab>
</md-tabs>
<md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="disabled = !disabled" ng-disabled="tabs.length <= 1">Disable/Enable</md-button>
```

I want neither of those. How can i change this?

Thanks

Comment: What would you like for it to do?  Remain on the same tab?

Comment: That would be good, for a starter. I would prefer a possibilty to decide what happens.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

`$watch` the `selectedIndex`.

```
var justDisabled = false;
$scope.disableTabs = function() {
  $scope.disabled = !$scope.disabled;
  justDisabled = true;
}

$scope.$watch('selectedIndex', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  if(justDisabled) {
    $scope.selectedIndex = oldValue;
    justDisabled = false;
  }
});
```

and the markup

```
<md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="disableTabs()" ng-disabled="tabs.length <= 1">Disable/Enable</md-button>
```

Now you have absolute power (and it's all done in one digest)!

http://codepen.io/astynax777/pen/NRzPEp

Comment: I dont like this solution, because i hate adding too many watches. As it stands this watch will be triggered quite frequently.

Comment: That's fine, but I believe the `$timeout` solution would trigger a new `$digest` call which would check all your watches and be costly...

Comment: would this watch trigger before the tab is initially switched?

Comment: The view is updated after the digest so it would happen like this: 1) disabled tabs, 2) selectedIndex changed due to tabs being disabled, 3) selectedIndex watch triggered and set back to original value, 4) selectedIndex watch triggered one more time because it was reset back in step 3, 5) view updated.  With the `$timeout`, it has multiple digests, so the view would be updated twice I imagine: once when it moves to the end, and once when it moves back.

Comment: To clarify, though there seems to be no way to stop the selectedIndex from changing when disabling the tabs, using the `$watch` above would revert it back within the same digest so that you never see the tabs switch.

Answer (score 0):

Remain on the same tab - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/VKdYgk)

Markup

```
<md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="toggle()" ng-disabled="tabs.length <= 1">Disable/Enable</md-
```

JS

```
var currentSelection = $scope.selectedIndex;
var mySelection = 5;
$scope.toggle = function () {
    $scope.disabled = !$scope.disabled;
    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.selectedIndex = currentSelection;

        /* Or choose a selection
        $scope.selectedIndex = mySelection;
        */
    });
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to block the switch completely? Because this solution makes the tab switch back and forth.

Comment: @FrontendFriedrich The only way I could prevent the switch back and forth was to make the selectedIndex 0 - http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/KgZpEJ